# Mootools tween colour transition rejected for element children when colour specifically set in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

For your testing pleasure: http://jsfiddle.net/EnJSM/

Notice that if the "color: #6CB5FF;" was to be removed, the transition would work normally, instead it just works for the second part of the line.

I'm curious to how the solution turns out to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes - tween is single property, it's not overloaded - though it should accept either a single argument (target value from current) or an array [value1, value2] - so your code is not wrong.

you can try to use morph instead:

```
$("element").addEvent("click", function() {
    this.morph({
        color: ["#A00000", "#99CCFF"]
    });
});
```

tween seems to work fine here as well, having said that. when you say `it's rejected,` what do you mean? nothing happens? you get an exeption? in what browser? which mootools? do you have `!important` in the css? question is too broad to answer as is.

if you want BOTH els to change color, use this:

```
$("element").set("tween", {
    onStart: function() {
        this.element.addClass("tweening");
    },
    onComplete: function() {
        this.element.removeClass("tweening");
    }


}).addEvent("click", function() {
    $("element").tween('color', ["#A00000", "#99CCFF"]);
});
```

where

```
#element.tweening strong {
    color: inherit;
}
```

this will temporary disable the styling while you animate.

Comment: I assumed you would check the provided demo on jsfiddle.net.
Simply, clicking on the element activates the wanted colour transition, but only on the last text "efgh", since it's not wrapped into "<strong>".
CSS, again provided in the demo, does not have "!important" flag.
Additionally, the morph function does not provide wanted result:
http://jsfiddle.net/EnJSM/2/

Comment: i checked the demo. it works in the way i'd expect it to work, given the cdoe. hence me asking you about your browser--though i guess i don't understand your question. do you actually want the CHILD element to also change colour?

Comment: Firefox Nightly 13.0a1 (2012-02-02) on Linux, and yes I want the CHILD element to change colour too.